# lens review/finder site cw questions

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

See: [What are some good online tools for finding compatible lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17105/what-are-some-good-online-tools-for-finding-compatible-lenses). If left open, this should probably be a community wiki: it lends itself to the "objective list of resources" kind of answering that CW works best for.

There's some debate, I think, on whether those sort of lists add value at Stack Exchange overall; I'm not going to take a position on that. The question is: should that Q be left as it is, or should it be merged with [Where can I find reviews of lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/where-can-i-find-reviews-of-lenses), and that question edited to include non-review lens-sorter sites, which *are* already listed in the answers?

Comment: Also, if someone is really bored, I think refactoring the existing CW so that each site is an individual answer rather than having the answer in the question would be a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the heads up, Matt. I am not sure about merging the two questions...perhaps if we rename the merged result to "Where can I find lens resources?" or something of that nature.

I guess the question is, are two threads that service different purposes...one reviews, one lens compatibility, useful as a single combined thread? Or would it be better to refactor the older lens review wiki to extract the lens sorter sites into the first one you linked, separating the two results into more distinct sets of content?

Comment: Yeah, exactly....

Comment: Just wanted to say, as the question's asker, that whatever you decide is fine with me. I just found a neat site and wanted to share it. I would be happy to make my question a CW if I knew how; I don't see that option.

Answer (score 0):

I think lens review sites and lens databases usually go hand in hand. If the site has one, many times they have both. The "lenshawk" website that prompted this question is a database of lenses matched to your compatible body, and it blurs the line so far as linking directly to the Amazon reviews of each lens.

I use the site the-digital-picture as both my lens database and my lens review site, I don't think we need to separate the two, although we would have to modify the existing CW subject to address both I think.

**I vote closing the new question, and editing the old to include both as they are very related.**